# Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() not returning private IP address of client

Tags: java

I have a client server program where the client is running on a pc with two ip address (public ip address visible via internet and private ip address). My server is running on a different network. When i connect both client and server using socket and use socket.getRemoteSocketAddress method of java at the server end, i get the public ip address of the client connection. Even if i use the InetAddress.getByName(socket.getInetAddress().getHostName) i still get the public address.

The problem is that i need the private address to be printed. Can you please let me know how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Only the client knows this. There is no way to retrieve an internal IP address from the server. The client would have to determine its local IP address and then send that information to the server.